# Sending email correctly so that they don't end up in spam

Tags: email, smtp, gmail, jakarta-mail

I am trying to send emails via GMail SMTP from my Java application, but in the end they tend to end up in spam or are directly rejected. The header looks like this:

```
----- Original message -----

X-Received: by 10.14.198.195 with SMTP id v43mr2942204een.62.1390413652657;
        Wed, 22 Jan 2014 10:00:52 -0800 (PST)
Return-Path: <mailer@goout.cz>
Received: from notta ([144.76.195.232])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPSA id m47sm29832554eey.7.2014.01.22.10.00.51
        for <target@gmail.com>
        (version=TLSv1 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA bits=128/128);
        Wed, 22 Jan 2014 10:00:52 -0800 (PST)
Date: Wed, 22 Jan 2014 10:00:52 -0800 (PST)
From: GoOut <mailer@goout.cz>
To: otevrel@gmail.com
Message-ID: <1591331921.1211390413651600.JavaMail.root@notta>
Subject: =?UTF-8?Q?GoOut_nov=C3=A9_akce?=
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

----- End of message -----
```

Sometimes I am getting this:

```
Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:

     target@gmail.com

Technical details of permanent failure:
Message rejected.  
See http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=69585 for more information.
```

I checked the documentation and I am not sure what I might be doing wrong. It does it even for my own email address.

Sent messages from my application looks like these - is there something wrong with the header? Is there something missing?

Comment: I guess you have to specify your GMail address as sender (`From:`) address when using GMail SMTP, but I'm not sure.

Comment: But FROM field was set: `From: GoOut <mailer@goout.cz>`

Comment: No, I mean, you have to use **your GMail address** as sender, like `mailer@gmail.com`. Otherwise, GMail would be the biggest spam gateway ever known to mankind.

Comment: Ah, I did not explain myself correctly. `goout.cz` is a google apps account.

Comment: Hey were you able to figure this out? Getting the same issue here

Answer (score 0):

As the comment above says, try using your Gmail address as the From address.  See also this [Gmail help page](https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=22370) if you want to send from a different address.

Comment: Ah, I did not explain myself correctly. `goout.cz` is a google apps account.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of things that could cause your messages to be filtered by receiving MTA's spam filters.  It could be that your mail server's DNS is not forwarding and reversing correctly, your mail server is not identifying itself to other mail servers correctly, your mail server's IP address could be blacklisted, or a host of other things.  An SPF record will also help, if you don't have one setup already.  See [Outgoing Listing-Mail stucks in Spam-Filter since I moved to a new Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17789160/outgoing-listing-mail-stucks-in-spam-filter-since-i-moved-to-a-new-server/17790088#17790088) for more info.